# Extracting information between strings in a text file

Tags: python, string, text, extract

I have a data file structured as such:

```
handle:trial1

key_left:3172

key_up:

xcoords:12,12,12,15........

ycoords:200,200,206,210,210......

t:20,140,270,390.....

goalx:2

goaly:12

fractal:images/file.png

seen:true

pauseTimes:

fractal:images/file2.png

seen:False

pauseTimes:

...
...
```

I want to extract only the information after the `goaly` line and up until the `pauseTimes` line. If I knew the `goaly` values for all trials I could just specify that line and extract data between `goaly:` and `pauseTimes`, but I will not know ahead of time what the value of any `goaly` is as they are dynamically generated.

How can I use the string `"goaly"` to ID that line and then extract all following lines until the `pauseTimes` line?

Comment: Have you tried anything? This should be a fairly routine task in python. If you post a code sample, we can help where you're having issues.

Comment: I did, I was using line.strip() but that required (I believe) the exact contents of the line. Using line.startswith should do the trick. I'll revert after I customize the code if I have additional issues! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just loop and track with a state variable whether you care about the line or not.  I like to track parsing state like this with a generator to keep it separated from the handling code.  For your example, here is the generator:

```
def parse(infile):
    returning = False
    trial = None
    for line in infile:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if not line:
            continue

        if line.startswith('handle:'):
            trial = line[len('handle:'):]

        if line.startswith('goaly:'):
            returning = True
        elif line.startswith('pauseTimes:'):
            returning = False

        if returning:
            yield trial, line
```

And here is how you would use it:

```
for trial, line in parse(open('test.txt', 'r')):
    print(trial, line)
```

with the bonus feature of tracking which trial you are in.

Comment: That works great thanks, and is very instructive which I appreciate as a more or less beginner.

Comment: One more noob questions - how do you save the output of print(trial, line) to a variable? Use another loop? Thanks in advance.

Comment: My beginner attempt was new_data = parse(infile) but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
extracting = False
with open('path/to/file') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('goaly:'):
            extracting = True
        if extracting:
            # I'm not really sure how you want to receive this
            # data, but that's what would go here....
        if line.startswith('pauseTimes:'):
            extracting = False
```